# Getting a end-of-line char by converting char to decimals

Tags: c

I am trying to read a string of integers and convert them to digits 0-9 inside the code from the ascii representation so addition with a second number later on will be easier.
My problem here lies only in the fact that my program doesn't only convert my chars(numbers) I typed into the console but also the end-of-line char which I tried to exclude by my condition inside my convert_ascii_to_decimal function.
My result gives me the correct decimals but an additionally 100 which I don't understand. This always results in turning the condition for the function "ensure" to false.
Any ideas how I can get rid of that? THX!
(Also my professor wants "int size" to be a parameter of the function convert_ascii_to_decimal which I don't understand what for.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 5

int read_array(char* number, int size);
int convert_ascii_to_decimal(char* number, int size);
void ensure(int condition, char* message);

int main(void){

    char number1[MAX + 1];
    int i, r, size1;

    r = read_array(number1, MAX);
    ensure(r == 0, "Ur number is too long");


    size1 = convert_ascii_to_decimal(number1, MAX);
    //ensure(size1 != 0, "The number contains something other than digits.\n"); 

    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(number1); i++)
        printf("%d", number1[i]);   

    return 0;

}

int read_array(char* number, int size) {


    printf("\nEnter an integer number at a maximum of 5 digits please.\n");
    int result = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char* i = number;
    do {
        scanf("%c", i);
        count++;
    } while (*i++ != '\n');
    *i = '\0';

    if (count > size + 1)
        result = 1;

    return result;
}


void ensure(int condition, char* message) {
    if (!condition) {
        printf(message);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


int convert_ascii_to_decimal(char* number, int size) {

    int count = 0;
    char* i = number;
    while(*i != '\0'){
        if (*i >= 48 && *i <= 57){
            *i -= '0';
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
            break;
        }

    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: it checks if the user typed a correct number of numbers into the console. If its more than 5 it will complain. No I want to convert my ascii numbers into actual digits from 0 to 9 so addition with a second number will be easier later on.

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm so tired that nothing makes sense to me right now:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you post-increment `i` in the loop header, and then set the character *after* `'\n'` to zero. Your `do`/`while` loop

```
do {
    ...
} while (*i++ != '\n');
```

ends when `\n` is stored at `*i`. After that, `i` is incremented, so it points to the character one past the end of line character.

To fix this, change this line

```
*i = '\0';
```

to this:

```
*(i-1) = '\0';
```

Comment: thanks. of course! Do you have any idea why a parameter size in the function ascii_to_decimal makes sense?

Comment: @ChrisBo You are not using that parameter correctly: you should be checking it in the `do`/`while` loop to avoid a buffer overrun.

Comment: ok I suppose ur talking about the read_array function but what about the asii_to_decimal function.

Comment: @ChrisBo Your `ascii_to_decimal` function does not need `size` - indeed, it's not used there at all.